# List of Lists lambda

Tags: c#, list

I have an object that contains a number of lists that are all derived from ObjectCollection(T) : IObjectCollection (T)

```
public P()
{
    A = new A();
    C = new C();
    H = new H();
    M = new M();
    T = new T();
}
```

I want to be able to iterate through these lists as though they were one list, but I want top keep the lists separated, AND I don't want to project a new list from these. So I thought about doing soemthing like this in the P class:

```
public T GetObject<T>(IUniqueIdentifier identifier) where T : class
{
    T dObject = A.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GuidId == identifier) as T ?? H.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GuidId == identifier) as T ?? M.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GuidId == identifier) as T ?? T.FirstOrDefault(a => a.GuidId == identifier) as T;
    return Object;
}
```

All objects in the lists derive from ObjectBase and have a GuidId public property.

But that seems a rubbish solution. So then I thought about doing something like this:

```
List<IObjectCollection<ObjectBase>> _objects = new List<IObjectCollection<ObjectBase>>{A,C,H,M,T};
```

and then using something like this (code is not exact!):

```
public T GetObject<T>(Guid identifier) where T : class
{
    T Object = _objects.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Contains(identifier)) as T;
    return Object;
}
```

But alas, I just can't work out the right way of doing it.

Any help appreciated.

Stu.

Comment: This seems like is pretty close to working... have you tried `_objects.FirstOrDefault(c => c.GuidId == identifier)) as T` in your `GetObject<T>` method?

Comment: Or maybe `A.Concat(C).Concat(H).Concat(M).Concat(T).FirstOrDefault(a => a.GuidId == identifier)` ?

Comment: How about just creating a method like `IEnumerable<T> EnumerateAll()` that simply uses `yield return` in each of a bunch of `foreach` loops?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this not work? Although I don't think I have enough context to really get why you're doing it this way.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var myObj = GetObject(guid, A, C, H, M, T);
}

public T GetObject<T>(Guid identifier, params IObjectCollection<T>[] collections)
    where T : ObjectBase
{
    foreach (var collection in collections)
    {
        var item = collection.FirstOrDefault(o => o.GuidId == identifier);
        if (item != null) return item;
    }
    return default;
}

public class ObjectBase
{
    public Guid GuidId { get; }
}
```